# onmouseover="this.click()" for Android

Tags: javascript, android, click, onmouseover

I am using this code:

```
<a href="http://www...." onmouseover="this.click()">Link</a>
```

I know that's not working with Android Browser.

Which (javascript) code works with Android Browser too?

Thanks for all helps.

Comment: how do you expect mouseover to work on touch screens ?

Comment: sort of out of curiosity ; why on *earth* would you want to do this?

Comment: @mrid you can hook a mouse up to an android device. Maybe OP is making something for an android kiosk with a mouse.

Comment: Can you please tell us what exactly you want to achieve so we can help ? Why not using simple `onclick` event ? if you just want to navigate to a new page, you won't even need that

Answer (score 0):

I have used the codes

```html
<span onmouseover = function x() onmouseout = function y()>'some text' </span>
```

to pop up a window showing info. from a glossary file relating  to 'some text'. The functions are in a script file. This was written for PC/Laptop browsers but I find it works in Android browsers also provided pop ups are not disabled.  Example: https://carnatic2000.tripod.com/JSA/intro4.htm In Laptop pop up comes on moving the mouse over the words in brown color and in Android on touching.